# Chakra ui vue3 vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, chakra-ui

[image: error I got]
Does chakra ui work with vue3 vite, vue cli is currently in maintenance mode…and am having trouble using chakra ui with vue vite…I keep getting an error and my dom is blank

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not ready just yet: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui-vue/issues/116#issuecomment-762594573